# WordPress - get_template_directory() returning parent theme's url

Tags: php, html, wordpress, include

I'm trying to make a short HTML component in a PHP file to include it later in different pages of a site.

I want to use `get_template_directory()` cause I thought It would return my actual theme's root URL. The theme I am using is a child theme. Instead, it seems like it is returning the parent's root directory URL.

What would be the correct way of doing all this?
The piece of HTML I'm trying to include in some different pages as a component with some buttons. But I'm not including it as a plugin.

I checked everything in my child-theme's folder and everything AFAIK looks ok.

I have this code in function.php and I think it's ok from a previous question I asked here before.

```
<?php
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'adapt_child_enqueue_styles');
function adapt_child_enqueue_styles(){
    wp_dequeue_style('theme-responsive');
    wp_enqueue_style('theme-child-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/style.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('theme-child-responsive', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/css/responsive.css');
}
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using get_template_directory(), use

```
get_stylesheet_directory()
```

That will return the child theme directory rather than the parent theme directory. Read more here https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to make a short HTML component in a PHP file to include it
>   later in different pages of a site.

What you're describing is known as a template part. While it is possible to use an `include` statement coupled with `get_stylesheet_directory()` there's a better way to handle it: `get_template_part()`.

As another user has already pointed out; the issue you're facing at the moment is due to use of the wrong function. `get_template_directory()` will return a path to the parent theme whereas `get_stylesheeet_directory()` will return a path to the current/child theme.

Example using include:

```
include( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/my-template-part.php' );
```

Replacement using `get_template_part()`:

```
get_template_part( 'my-template-part' );
```

The `get_template_part()` function is more robust than a simple include statement. Take a look at the docs for more info: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/

Comment: Where should I put then the part php file?

Comment: It's going to be relative to your theme root. If you use it as shown above then it will first look in your child theme for my-template-part.php. If it can't be found there it will check the parent theme. You'll likely want to move your template into a folder. E.g. `get_template_part( 'template-parts/my-template-part' );`